Content only partially flows around consecutive floats of varying widths
Lets say I have defined a set of floats that start out wide, become narrower as you go down the page, and then become wider again, creating a sort of hourglass shape (well, one half of an hour glass, split down the middle).
Now if I add content to the container of these floats, I would expect that the content flows fully around all of the floated elements and fills the "valley" in the middle of hour glass.
However, as you can see in this example, the content does not fully fill the "valley" and seems to stop at some seemingly arbitrary halfway point.
Is this expected behavior (and is there any way to force the behavior I want?)
Here is a demo of content not fully flowing to the furthest float:
https://jsfiddle.net/nv9th230/2/
HTML:
<div class="main">
<div>

</div>
  <div class="float size1">
    float
  </div>
  <div class="float size2">
    float
  </div>
  <div class="float size3">
    float
  </div>
  <div class="float size4">
    float
  </div>
  <div class="float size5">
    why doesnt content touch me
  </div>
  <div class="float size4">
    float
  </div>
  <div class="float size3">
    float
  </div>
  <div class="float size2">
    float
  </div>
  <div class="float size1">
    float
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
    This is the content. Why does the content not flow all the way to the left.
    Instead of going all the way to the left, it stops short.
  </div>
</div>

CSS:
  width: 1000px;
  clear: both;
}

.float {
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  clear: both;
}


.size1 {
  width: 400px;
}
.size2 {
  width: 300px;
}
.size3 {
  width: 200px;
}
.size4 {
  width: 100px;
}
.size5 {
  width: 70px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px;
}

.size1 {
  width: 400px;
}
.size2 {
  width: 300px;
}
.size3 {
  width: 200px;
}
.size4 {
  width: 100px;
}
.size5 {
  width: 50px;
}

.content {
  height: 100px;
}


It isn’t stopping short. Remember that it has to leave space for descenders so it looks as though it ought to be able to get that word further to the left, but in fact there isn’t enough vertical space left.

Looks like a Chromium optimisation bug. Works fine in Firefox.

Stops short in Safari IOS also. Does it depend on exactly where the bottom of characters (as opposed to the baseline) is deemed to be?

@AHaworth good question, I gave it a try with a shorter amount of content (and got rid of the content's containing div) and it still stops short at the same location: https://jsfiddle.net/gonctb83/1/

Not sure what exactly you need to achieve, but maybe https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside would be worth looking into.

Apologies, my comment was after trying on Safari IOS where there was just what looked like a single line not across far enough. Now tried on Chrome/Edge and see what you mean, there is a large area not moved across.

@C3roe Interesting - I didn't know about 'shape-outside'! I'm not sure it would easily work for my case since I also have content inside the floats that I wish to render.  (Although maybe it could be made to work if I used a polygon in the same shape of all the floats, and positioned above them..)
